# Find all solutions to $m^2 − n^2 = 105$, for which both m and n are integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, diophantine-equations

Can I get a little help for  this question?

Find all the integer solutions to $m^2 − n^2 = 105$.

Comment: using the fundamental theorm of factorization!

Comment: Hint: $(m-n)(m+n)=3 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$.

Comment: I've seen this hint given before but I fail to see the relevance? How is that meant to solve the question?

Comment: For example: m-n = 3 and m+n = 5*7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(m+n)(m-n) = 105$

$(m+n)(m-n) = 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$

4 Solutions :

Solve them by yourself.

$m-n = 1$, $m+n = 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$.

$m-n = 3$, $m+n = 5\cdot 7$-

$m-n = 5$, $m+n = 3\cdot 7$.

$m-n = 7$, $m+n = 3\cdot 5$.

But notice those $m^2 - n^2$, it's clear that $m$ and/or $n$ could be negative - it would not change a thing, thus $4\times 4=16$ solutions in total.